# MYSQL SELECT To fetch rows from two tables with or without a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am looking for some help with a `MYSQL` query. I have two tables, one contains a list of `tickets` and the other is a list of `members`.

**Table Tickets:
ticket_id,
member_id
Table Members:
member_id**

A member can but doesn't have to be assigned to a ticket. What I would like to do is select all the tickets and then if the member_id field is set in the tickets table fetch the member information as well.

One approach is to do a `SELECT * FROM Tickets` and then  loop through in PHP and check if the member_id field is set. If set then do another query on the `members` table to fetch the corresponding information. The only problem with this is that it would be a large number of queries.

Is there any way to fetch all the results in one join query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select *
from Tickets
Left Join Members On tickets.member_id = members.member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tickets left outer join members on tickets.member_id = members.ticket_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, t.member_id FROM tikcets t LEFT JOIN members m ON t.member_id = m.member_id
```

This will give you all the tickets whether they have been assigned to a member or not.
You should add to the query the additional fields that you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, m.member_id
FROM tickets AS t LEFT OUTER JOIN members AS m 
ON t.member_id = m.member_id
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will cause all results from tickets to be returned, and any match from members, not disqualifying the ticket records, so this could do the trick.